# How can I push an array into aggregate pipeline and pull it one level up?

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB and I am developing a software by C# and MongoDB. My data structure is like this

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Title": "myTitle",
  "Geners": [ "Drama", "Action" ],
  "Category": 1,
  "Casts": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "myName",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Age": 35
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "herName",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Age": 30
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "hisName",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Age": 45
    }
  ]
}
```

This is just one document and I have about 5 million documents. I want to run a query like below to count the records based on `Category` and shows me how many movie do I have in each category and I want to put Casts field in result.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {
    $group:{"_id":"$Category", "count": {$sum:1},
    "Casts":{$push:"$Casts"}} 
    }
])
```

this is close to something I want but the problem is, it puts `Casts` data in second level of array like `{"Id":1, ... , "Casts":[[{},{},...]]}` but I need it like this `{"Id":1, ... , "Casts":[{},{},...]}`
How can I show the data like that?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of unique entries in the Casts array? Or are duplicates acceptable? Oh, and this has nothing to do with C#. lol

Comment: In this case I want to put exactly all of the data which is inside the Casts. For example if I have 3 documents in this category and each one has Casts with 3 objects. In the result I should have Casts including 9 objects. and about C# you are right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If duplicates are acceptable, then the following aggregation will suffice:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    { $unwind:"$Casts"},
    {
    $group:{"_id":"$Category", "count": {$sum:1},
    "Casts":{$push:"$Casts"}} 
    }
])
```

Update: 
Since you need the count to be valid, there's a few more hoops to jump through.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    { $group:{"_id":"$Category", "count": {$sum:1}, "Casts":{$addToSet:"$Casts"}}},
    {$unwind:"$Casts"},
    {$unwind:"$Casts"},
    { $group:{"_id":"$_id", "count": {$first:"$count"}, "Casts":{$addToSet:"$Casts"}}},
])
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: @Mhmd let me know if the updated answer helps at all.

Comment: Great. This is exactly the answer. Thank you very much.